# How to: Setup a language controller in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization

LanguageController has an object 't' with all texts for the current language like so:

```
this.t = {lang:"en", headline: "Welcome!", ...}
```

When I use this in my template

```
html(ng-app="app", ng-controller="LanguageController as l", lang="{{ l.t.lang }}")
```

I've got two problems:

- My controller gets called twice
- If I assign `this.t` with a different language (e.g. using ng-click when clicking a button, I would expect to see the live update in my `lang` attribute, but I don't.

How can I make the controller only be called once and update the expression as soon as `this.t` changes?

**Edit**
Here is the controller source:

```
app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

app.controller 'LanguageController', ['$http', ($http) ->

  @.t = {} # current texts
  @.locale = null

  # Text object that contains all the strings
  @.texts =
    'en': {}
    'ja': {}

  @.setLang = (lang) ->
    @.locale = lang
    @.t = @.texts[lang]

   @.getText = ->
     # ... GETTING THE TEXT
     # ...
     ctrl = @
     $http.jsonp('...')
       # ...
       ctrl.texts = data
       ctrl.t = ctrl.texts[ctrl.locale]

  @.detectLang = ->
    lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage
    if lang.indexOf('-') != -1
      lang = lang.split('-')[0]

    if lang != "ja"
      lang = "en"

    @.setLang(lang)

  @.init = ->
    @.detectLang()
    @.getText()

  @.init()
]
```

Comment: Can you post app config and controller code?

Comment: @dfsq Here you go, `setLang` is getting called by ng-click and my text object is correctly populated, but it won't synchronize with the view when it changes. I bet it's a very simple mistake, I'm very new to angular.